# How should I handle unit testing for a bug we don't intend to fix?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net

A big chunk of our codebase has no unit tests whatsoever. We've been writing unit tests for any new code we add, but we're only just now starting to go back and add unit tests for the existing code. While writing & running unit tests for an existing calculation method, I found a bug: there's a particular input edge case that the calculation does not handle correctly.

The bug has never been detected before because it's not actually reachable in the application; the particular input that hits the bug is a subset of a group of inputs that are trivial and handled directly rather than being sent to the somewhat expensive calculation method. My boss has decided that since the bug can't be hit from the application, it's not worth digging through the calculation method to fix it.

Using XUnit, how should I best mark this bug as something we're aware of but have chosen not to fix? A failed test would break our build automation, so I can't just leave it as is. The input that fails is currently being generated as part of a `PropertyData` for a `Theory`.

Does XUnit have a special indicator for this? Should I adjust the method that generates the inputs for the `PropertyData` to exclude that case, add a comment explaining why, and then put in a skipped `Fact` covering that case?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have unit tests providing input data that your requirements state are not supported cases.  In this case you don't have a bug, you simply have requirements stating that the given input is not supported and is considered invalid.

If you really want to, you can have tests that provide invalid input and assert failure, if you choose to make it an explicit requirement that this input must fail.  If you don't want to do that, simply don't create tests for use cases you don't have.

Comment: It *is* a supported case, it's just not handled by the general-case code that I'm currently adding tests for. My concern is that, since the performance hit for this calculation method isn't very bad, someone later may decide to simplify the code by having it handle the trivial cases as well (they are, after all, trivial, and the calculation method would reasonably be expected to handle them).

Comment: @ObliviousSage So clearly you want to *make* this case unsupported, given that your method doesn't support it, you have no need to support it, and you have no intention of supporting it later.  It wasn't unsupported before, but it is now.  You can make it explicit by explicitly testing that it throws, if you want.

Comment: Tragically, it does not throw, nor is it going to be modified to throw. It merely returns an incorrect result. Are you suggesting that I explicitly test that it returns the wrong result (presumably with a title that includes "This Is Still Broken" or something along those lines)?

Comment: @ObliviousSage You should modify it to throw, if you want it to remain an unsupported case and want to make that explicit.  That is by far the most effective way of preventing someone from changing the code to use the unsupported input without realizing that it doesn't work.

Comment: The calling code covers the edge cases NOW. But what if next week/month/year/ the calling code is changed and suddenly the faulted function is confronted with exactly those cases? Solution: Add tests for those edge cases at the top of your "faulted" function and throw/assert if it is being called with those edge cases. As long as the calling code is behaving as it does now, it cannot ever throw. But once the calling code changes, the problem will reveal itself quickly. Then write a unit test which shows, that calling that function with the edge cases will throw/assert. Done :)

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the fact balances between not running the test but leaving noticeable warning that this is something to take care of in the future.
Alternatively, you can categorize the test and config the runner to skip it, see, e.g., the Category Sample [v1](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/tree/v1/samples/TraitExtensibility),[v2](https://github.com/xunit/samples/tree/master/TraitExtensibility)